# Is there a fast way to define a Polygon using clicks?

Tags: gmlib

I'm using the GMLib 1.0.0 Final, in order to create a polygon (with Editable = True) i catch the OnClick event of TGMMap (based on megademo) to add the points, but when i add several points more than 3 in fact, the polygon takes a long long time to draw on map, increasing the update time while more points are added using AddLinePoint.
Is there a fast way to define a Polygon using clicks?

Answer (score 0):

I have done the test and I have seeing that with Polyline.Editable = false work good but with Editable = False have the problem that you say.

I will try to investigate it and fix it in new version.

Regards